# Set current time as min date while using datetime picker

Tags: jquery-ui, datetimepicker

I am new to javascript and jquery.
I am using Trent Richardson's time picker [library](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/). I want to make the current time as the default date and the minDate.

```
$("#date").datetimepicker('option', 'setDate', (new Date())),
$("#date").datetimepicker({
    onSelect: function (selectedDateTime){
        $("#rundate").datetimepicker('option', 'minDate', (new Date()));
    }
});
```

This doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The current library need to init instance to work Ex: .datetimepicker({...}) or datetimepicker()

```
$("#date").datetimepicker('option', 'setDate', (new Date()));
$("#rundate").datetimepicker(); //You need to init this before assign min date
$("#date").datetimepicker({
  onSelect: function(selectedDateTime) {
    $("#rundate").datetimepicker('option', 'minDate', (new Date()));
  }
});
```

For more details I will refactor your code again.

```
//Init steps      
$("#date").datetimepicker();
$("#rundate").datetimepicker();

//define variables steps
$("#date").datetimepicker('option', 'setDate', (new Date()));
$("#date").datetimepicker('option', 'onSelect', function(selectedDateTime) {
  $("#rundate").datetimepicker('option', 'minDate', (new Date()));
});
```

you can try a live demo [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/7XTv6XTp0sfZ9HYZpSwe?p=preview)